# Create Website in IIS using commands in core php

Tags: php, iis

Want to create website in my IIS with cmd commands using php. I have found various command in cmd but how to handle that in php

Commands:

1. #cd c:\Windows\System32\inetsrv  (that goes to folder)
2. #appcmd add site /name:windows.testing.net /bindings:http://*:80 /physicalpath:”C:\sites\windows.testing.net” (that creates the website in IIS)

This get's the work done from cmd.
How to do that programmatically please help
Thanks

```
// i changed my around something like this it doesn't executes nor shows any error
<?php 
$webUrl         = "TestSite";
$physical_Path  = "path";
$psPath         = "powershell.exe";
$psDIR          = "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\"; 
$psScript       = 'New-IISSite -Name "'.$webUrl.'" -BindingInformation "*:80:'.$webUrl.'" -PhysicalPath "'.$physical_Path.'"';
$runScript      = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD         = $psPath." ".$runScript;
//echo $runCMD;exit;
$output         = shell_exec($runCMD);
echo('<pre>');echo($output); echo('</pre>');
?>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)?

Comment: But can we do that with which goes to the specified directory and then execute the above commands?

Comment: Have you tried?  Also, do you necessarily need to change the working directory?  Or should you instead just supply full paths where needed?  Relying on the current working directory when automating tasks usually isn't a good idea, it's best to be explicit with paths, either absolute or relative to a known system path in an environment variable.

Comment: Yes tried but stuck in paths. Simply can say how i can add website to IIS using php programmatically.

Comment: So you want a site with PHP script running in IIS which will create another IIS website programatically, is that correct? Better hope you've got amazing security on that first site. Anyway PHP can't do this natively. You just need to get the PHP to run a batch or powershell script containing the necessary commands.

Comment: @self_divident: I'm afraid "but stuck in paths" doesn't describe a specific attempt or a specific problem encountered during that attempt.  PHP functions such as `system()` and `exec()` can be used to execute command-line (system) commands.  For the `appcmd` tool you're trying to use, [it has documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe).  These are two separate things.  First, figure out the commands you want to execute.  *Then* execute them from PHP.

Comment: No ADyson i have site already built in php just want a form where i can create iis website entry .

Comment: Well ok, but that's the scenario isn't it - a site in PHP which has a feature where you can add another site. So yes, you need top-quality security to avoid someone making lots of sites you don't want, and which could be a vulnerability, and yes again you just need to get PHP to exec() the relevant command(s).

Comment: The only correct one with finer control is the IIS REST API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis-administration/ All others require your PHP site to run as administrator which raises security risks to a higher level.

Comment: So what output do you get from the new script?

Comment: blank output, want to get the result if the command successfully executed or not

Comment: Does the command output anything if you run it from a normal command prompt?

Comment: I got it done by using following php exec() on local server.
exec(powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command New-IISSite -Name "www.test.com" -BindingInformation "*:80:www.test.com" -PhysicalPath "C:\xampp\htdocs" 2>&1);

Comment: Glad you solve it, but you should write that as an Answer below, for the benefit of others (and you can also get upvotes if others find it useful). Comments are not searchable, so the solution right now is not visible to anyone else searching on Stackoverflow or Google. You're encouraged to answer your own questions, that's not a problem. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got it done by using following php exec() on local server.

```
<?php 
$output         = null;
$retval         = null;
$successMsg     = "";
$errorMsg       = "";
exec(powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command New-IISSite -Name "www.test.com" -BindingInformation "*:80:www.test.com" -PhysicalPath "C:\xampp\htdocs" 2>&1);
if(empty($output)){
    $successMsg     = "Done";
}else{
    $errorMsg       = $output[0];
}
?>
```

Comment: You will need to provide read right to your iis_iusrs